# How do I add an object to an array without the need of reloading the page to see the result?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web, frontend

I want to add to an array that looks like `const [product, setProduct]=useState([])` and product looks something like `product = {product_name: "yes", product_price: "2", product_vendor: "someone"}`.

I tried to look up on the internet but none of the examples really worked in my case. Most of them did insert a object into the array but with no data.

Comment: https://github.com/maghiarul/auth/blob/master/src/Dashboard.tsx

This is the page where I want to implement that , if it helps you .

Comment: You are setting the initialState as an array, but, the product is an object, are you sure that's correct? And based on your gist file, I can't make out the type of your `product` state

Comment: normally you don't need to reload the page to see changes when you set state in react, react will do it for you.

Comment: have you try `setProduct(p => p.concat(newThing))`?

Comment: i think it would've worked if i didn't had the `id` which bugs me right now. it duplicates for some reason

Comment: i think i need it now to generate a new id.

Comment: I managed to make it work ! Thanks @Layhout !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.